# Decouple trait object lifetimes in generic function

Tags: rust

Given:

```rust
pub trait SomeTrait {}

pub fn foo<T: ?Sized>(arg1: &mut T, arg2: Box<T>) -> Box<T> {
    arg2
}

struct S {
    b: Box<dyn SomeTrait>
}

pub fn bar(a0: &mut S, a1: &mut dyn SomeTrait, a2: Box<dyn SomeTrait>) {
    a0.b = foo(a1, a2);
}
```

I have a generic function `foo`. When it's used in `bar` it seems as though `T` gets a type of `dyn SomeTrait + 'static` which seems to force `arg1` to have lifetime of `'static' and gives the following error:

```
error[E0759]: `a1` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> <source>:12:12
   |
11 | pub fn bar(a0: &mut S, a1: &mut dyn SomeTrait, a2: Box<dyn SomeTrait>) {
   |                            ------------------ this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
12 |     a0.b = foo(a1, a2);
   |            ^^^^--^^^^^
   |                |
   |                ...is used and required to live as long as `'static` here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0759`.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Is there a way force `arg1` to have an independent lifetime? i.e. decouple it from the `'static` so that the code compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way force `arg1` to have an independent lifetime? i.e. decouple it from the `'static` so that the code compiles?

No. There's a single type parameter `T`, and in the case of a trait object type, there's a lifetime bound embedded in the type, and so the lifetime bound will be the same every time `T` is used.

What we *can* do is relax the `'static` requirement instead...

---

The `'static` requirement comes from the assignment to `a0.b`. The type of `a0.b` is `Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'static>`: `'static` is inferred here, because lifetime parameters must always be explicit on structs. However, the `&mut dyn SomeTrait` and `Box<dyn SomeTrait>` parameters on `bar` have anonymous lifetimes instead, hence the error.

The solution is to introduce a lifetime parameter on `S` and use it in the trait object, and then adjust `bar`'s signature to make the lifetimes agree.

```
pub trait SomeTrait {}

pub fn foo<T: ?Sized>(arg1: &mut T, arg2: Box<T>) -> Box<T> {
    arg2
}

pub struct S<'a> {
    b: Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'a>,
}

pub fn bar<'a>(a0: &mut S<'a>, a1: &mut (dyn SomeTrait + 'a), a2: Box<dyn SomeTrait + 'a>) {
    a0.b = foo(a1, a2);
}
```